# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.6.0

I tried installing tensorflow with:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

And then to test it:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I tried a couple of solution found online but without success. 
Also with `pip list` I get:

- tensorboard         1.12.1
- tensorflow          1.12.0

There is no tensorflow-gpu in `pip list` either.

I tried uninstalling tensorflow and install tensorflow 1.10 instead but I am not getting :

C:\Users\a>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in module
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 52, in 
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in 
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in 
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.

Any idea on what could be happening?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: post output of `where python` and `where pip3`

Comment: where Python : 
C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

Comment: where pip3 :
C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip3.exe